# iOS-How to use NSOperationQueue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

I'm using `NSOperationQueue` in my app,I write it with Objective C.And I'm currently converting my app to Swift.I wonder how can I use `NSOperationQueue` in Swift?

Here is my code on objective c

```
 -(NSOperationQueue*)operationQueue
{
    if(_operationQueue == nil) {
        _operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    }

    return _operationQueue;
}
```

And I already tried in swift

```
func operationQueue() -> NSOperationQueue{

    if(_operationQueue == nil){        
        _operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.new()
    }
}
```

But it gives me error:

> NSOperationQueue is not convertible to 'MirrorDispotion'

Answer (score 3):

The Objective-C code uses the `operationQueue` method (or property)
plus the `_operationQueue` instance variable for an "on-demand
initialization". The corresponding Swift 3 code would be
(for older versions, replace `OperationQueue` by `NSOperationQueue`):

```
class MyClass {

    var _operationQueue: OperationQueue?

    func operationQueue() -> OperationQueue {
        if _operationQueue == nil {
            _operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        }
        return _operationQueue!
    }

    // ...
}
```

The main errors in your code are that `_operationQueue` is not
defined, and that the function does not return a value.

But the same can be achieved in Swift much easier with a "lazy stored property":

```
class MyClass {

    lazy var operationQueue = OperationQueue()

    // ...
}
```

The value will be calculated *only once*, when the property is used
the first time:

```
let mc = MyClass()
print(mc.operationQueue) // operation queue is created and returned
print(mc.operationQueue) // same operation queue is returned
```

See "Lazy Stored Properties" in ["Properties"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) in the Swift documentation
for more information.

Answer (score 0):

new in objective-c is not really a function it's more an init

so in swift you could use

```
func operationQueue() -> NSOperationQueue{

    if(_operationQueue == nil){        
        _operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    }
    return _operationQueue
}
```